# quadratic in square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have $6$ equations and 6 unknowns, but I have trouble solving them. The problem I have is when I start substituting them, I get a quadratic formula in a square root that I can't simplify and reduce further.

The unknowns are $x, y, z, m, n, o$. (yes these are Cartesian coordinates), and the equations are:

1. $0=(x−a)^2+(y−b)^2+(z−c)^2−s^2$
2. $0=(x−d)^2+(y−e)^2+(z−f)^2−r^2$
3. $0=(m−a)^2+(n−b)^2+(o−c)^2−h^2$
4. $0=(m−d)^2+(n−e)^2+(o−f)^2−q^2$
5. $0=(m−u)^2+(n−v)^2+(o−w)^2−t^2$
6. $0=(x−m)^2+(y−n)^2+(z−o)^2−p^2$

Can anyone offer some guidance?

Thanks!

Comment: So, what system of equations are you left with after taking some out? Then we can go from there.

Comment: For example,  you can get the equation of x,y,z by 1-2. So you can get these 
3 equations, you can solve this.

Comment: The equations (in terms of unknowns) can be easily decoupled by considering $1, 2, 6$ separately from $3,4,5$.  Each is a system of three quadratic equations in three unknowns (or three spheres intersecting), solve them separately and take their union.

Comment: Thanks for the input. As mentioned, I have trouble solving it when I start applying the quadratic equation and then substituting. Can you show me your steps?

Comment: One trivial solution is all 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations $3,4,5$ can be solved independently. They are equations of spheres. Subtracting them in pairs, you get equations of planes. These are the planes of support of the intersection of the corresponding spheres (circles). Take the intersection of two planes to get a straight line. That straight line meets the three spheres in the same two points. (The resulting equation is quadratic).

Knowing $m,n,o$, the equations $1,2,6$ are of the same nature (three intersecting spheres).

In total, you will find four solutions.

---

**A vector solution:**

Assume the three spheres to be centered on $P,Q,R$, with radii $p,q,r$. We translate the three points to be $0,Q':=Q-P,R':=R-P$. Let the intersection point be $X$. We have

$$\begin{cases}(X-0)^2&=p^2,\\(X-Q')^2&=q^2,\\(X-R')^2&=r^2.\end{cases}$$

Eliminating $X^2$,

$$\begin{cases}2Q'X=Q'^2+p^2-q^2&,\\2R'X=R'^2+p^2-r^2&.\end{cases}$$

This is a linear system of two equations in three unknowns. Compute two distinct solutions, let $A$ and $B$, and the general solution is $X=A+tB'$ where $B':=B-A$.

Now, $$X^2=(A+tB')^2=p^2$$ is a quadratic equation in $t$ that gives the two solutions. Translate back by $P$.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I needed. I'm not sure what you meant in the X=A+tB' part, but I rearranged the 2 equations after eliminating X^2 to solve one coordinate as a function of another (say y as a function of z, and then x as a function of z), then substituting it back into X^2 = p^2 (to solve for z). I end up with a messy quadratic but I think that solves the system. Will test it arithmetically later.